# Having problems with fprintf

Tags: c, file-io, printf

I am trying to write a code that simulates an Anti-Virus scan, it scans 5 specific files and then creates a file named `AntiVirusLog.txt`. In this file it writes the results, for example `PSY.avi INFECTED`. An infected file is a file that contains the string in the file `youtubesign`.

My problem is when I try to print in the results to the file `AntiVirusLog.txt` it does not print anything and leaves the file blank.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#define BUZZ_SIZE 1024
int fast_scan(char *fname, char *str, FILE *fs);
int slow_scan(char *fname, char *str, FILE *fs);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char name[100];
    char choice[5];
    char buff[BUZZ_SIZE];
    FILE *f7, *f2;
    struct dirent *de;
    DIR *dr = opendir(argv[1]);
    if (dr == NULL)  // opendir returns NULL if couldn't open directory
    {
        printf("Could not open current directory");
        return 0;
    }
    f2 = fopen(argv[2], "rb");
    f7 = fopen("AntiVirusLog.txt", "wt");
    printf("Welcome to Amnon's Anti-Virus program\n which scan would you like to choose?:\n");
    printf("Fast: check only the first and the last 20% of the file\n Slow: Checks the entire file\n");
    printf("Enter fast for a fast scan and slow for a slow scan\n");
    scanf("%s", choice);
    if ((strcmp(choice, "slow"))==0)
    {
        while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(name, argv[1]);
            strcat(name, de->d_name);
            if((fgets(buff, BUZZ_SIZE, f2)) != NULL)
            {
                slow_scan(name, buff, f7);
            }
        }
    }
    if ((strcmp(choice, "fast")) == 0)
    {
        while ((de = readdir(dr)) != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(name, argv[1]);
            strcat(name, de->d_name);
            if ((fgets(buff, BUZZ_SIZE, f2)) != NULL)
            {
                fast_scan(name, buff, f7);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("The scan was made successfuly, check the file AntiVirusLog.txt to see the results\n");
    closedir(dr);
    fclose(f2);
    fclose(f7);
    system("PAUSE");
    return (0);
}
int slow_scan(char *fname, char *str, FILE *fs)
{
    int findres = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    char temp[BUZZ_SIZE];
    if ((fopen_s(&fp, fname, "rb")) != NULL)
    {
        return(-1);
    }
    while ((fgets(temp, BUZZ_SIZE, fp)) != NULL)
    {
        if ((strstr(temp, str)) != NULL)
        {
            fprintf(fs, "%s INFECTED\n", fname);
            findres++;
        }
    }
    if (findres==0)
    {
        fprintf(fs, "%s NOT INFECTED\n", fname);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
int fast_scan(char *fname, char *str, FILE *fs)
{
    int findres=0;
    int i, j, len, partlen;
    FILE *fp;
    if ((fopen_s(&fp, fname, "rb")) != NULL)
    {
        return(-1);
    }
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(fp);
    partlen = (len * 20) / 100;
    char *temp=malloc(partlen);
    while ((fgets(temp, BUZZ_SIZE, fp)) != NULL)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < partlen; i++)
        {
            if (temp[i]=str[i])
            {
                findres++;
            }
            if (temp[i] != str[i])
            {
                i = partlen + 1;
            }
            if (findres == partlen)
            {
                fprintf(fs, "%s INFECTED\n", fname);
                i = partlen + 1;
            }
        }
        for (j = len - partlen; j < len; j++)
        {
            if (temp[j] = str[j])
            {
                findres++;
            }
            if (temp[j] != str[j])
            {
                j = partlen + 1;
            }
            if (findres == partlen)
            {
                fprintf(fs, "%s INFECTED\n", fname);
                j = partlen + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (findres!= partlen)
    {
        fprintf(fs, "%s NOT INFECTED\n", fname);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: why you no check for `fopen()` in `main()`?

Comment: what does the `wt` modifier do on `fopen`? I don't think I've seen that before...

Comment: In addition to what other people said: there's no point in opening a file then just closing it, so you don't need `f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");` and `fclose(f);` (same for f2, f3, f4, f5, f6 but NOT f7). Also, your program never closes f7.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin It's in order to specify it's a text file.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx says you are right. interesting. it is definitely nonstandard.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin how to read that in English? [`de-de` to `en-us`] :-)

Comment: sorry, I updated the link. didn't even notice it's the wrong language.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin it's not _wrong_, it's just  that the community prefers (and understands) English. :-)

Answer (score 3):

There are primarily two major issues with your code

- **Point 1:** In your code, for the series of calls like

  ```
   search_sign(argv[1], buff, f7);
  ```

  you're using `buff` uninitialized. The `buff` is then passed as the second parameter of `search_sign()`, (to be accepted as `str`) which is again used as the search string in [`strstr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strstr.3.html).

  As `buff` is an *automatic* local variable, the initial content (value) is garbage (indeterminate) and hence , when used as the search key in `strstr()`,  will invoke  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
- **Point 2:** That said, [as my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729237/having-problems-with-fprintf/30729342#comment49514661_30729237),  you should always be checking the success of `fopen()` call(s) before using the returned file pointer any further.

Comment: a valid point, but probably not related to the described behaviour, except if it crashes in `strstr` before writing anything.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin well, maybe but a UB is UB, nothing specified, nothing's certain.

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin and if you meant to point out the `fopen()` check, notice my previous  comment on the answer itself. :-)

Comment: I know your point is valid (I upvoted it), I just don't think it is the root cause of the issues described by the OP in this case. I'm aware that his PC may be giving birth to neon-pink unicorns right now, but it is more likely that `strstr` just returns `NULL` in this case.

Answer (score -1):

I have used some of the advices listen and found some fixes of my own and now it works perfectly! the updated code looks like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define BUZZ_SIZE 1024
int search_sign(char *fname, char *str, FILE *fs);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buff[BUZZ_SIZE];
    FILE *f,*f7;
    f7 = fopen("AntiVirusLog.txt", "wt");
    f = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if ((fgets(buff, BUZZ_SIZE, f)) != NULL)
    {
        search_sign(argv[2], buff, f7);
        search_sign(argv[3], buff, f7);
        search_sign(argv[4], buff, f7);
        search_sign(argv[5], buff, f7);
        search_sign(argv[6], buff, f7);
    }
    printf("The scan was made successfuly, check the file AntiVirusLog.txt to see the results\n");
    fclose(f);
    fclose(f7);
    system("PAUSE");
    return (0);
}
int search_sign(char *fname, char *str, FILE *fs)
{
    int findres = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    char temp[BUZZ_SIZE];
    if ((fopen_s(&fp, fname, "rb")) != NULL)
    {
        return(-1);
    }
    while ((fgets(temp, BUZZ_SIZE, fp)) != NULL)
    {
        if ((strstr(temp, str)) != NULL)
        {
            fprintf(fs, "%s INFECTED\n", fname);
            findres++;
        }
    }
    if (findres==0)
    {
        fprintf(fs, "%s NOT INFECTED\n", fname);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: @chux You are correct, I forgot to add it, thank you! Edited.

Comment: you are still NOT checking if `fopen` for `f7` and `f` didn't fail